# Vapor pressure of a weak acid for a solution of its salt

Tags: vapor-pressure, salt

I need to calculate the vapor pressure of an acid in equilibrium with an aqueous solution of its salt. For example, say I have a solution of 40% potassium formate by mass in water at 50°C. How do I find the vapor pressure of formic acid in equilibrium with that liquid?

My best guess is that I first calculate the concentration of formate ions via
pKb = -log10([HB+][OH-]/[B]).

Then I can calculate the concentration of formic acid using pKa=log10([HA]/[A-][H+]).

Then I can use Raoult's law to estimate the partial pressure.

This is the best I can come up with, but it doesn't feel quite right to me. Does anyone recommend any corrections to this process?

Comment: Sounds fine altho why calculate formate? Just dissolve it calculate formic acid, convert to mole fractions and apply Raoult's law! do the calculations, a sniff test and head space analysis. an iterative calculation might be needed to account for the self- ionization of water. Report back the completed calculations and the analysis information.

Comment: Another point here is a 40% solution of  potassium formate in water by weight is very concentrated. You'd really need to use activities not concentrations in the calculations.

Comment: Note that I assume strong deviation from Raoult's law for formic acid/water or  formic acid/formate water solution  mixture, forming maximum azeotrope boiling at 107.2° C. and containing 22.5 wt. % water.

Comment: The part that probably doesn't feel right is that the two equilibria are coupled. However, if the amount shifting to the gas phase is small compared to solution it will hardly affect the solution concentrations, making your approach reasonable. You can check whether if it is so by using an iterative approach.